# Length of the curve $ \;\;x=3\cos\!\left(6t\right), \;\;y=18t+3\sin\!\left(6t\right), \, \;\; \;\; 0 \le t \le \frac{\pi }{6}\;\;$

Tags: calculus, integration, parametric

The length $\;L\;$ of the curve C given by

$\displaystyle \;\;x=3\cos\!\left(6t\right), \;\;y=18t+3\sin\!\left(6t\right), \, \;\; \displaystyle \;\; 0 \le t \le \frac{\pi }{6}\;\;$

is found by evaluating an integral of the form $\;\;{\displaystyle \int_{\alpha}^{\beta} \! J(t) \, dt }\;\;$ for a suitable integrand $\;J(t)\;$ and constants $\;\alpha\;$ and $\;\beta$.

---

So I found the derivative of:

x' = $18 \sin(6t)$

y' = $18 + 18 \cos(6t)$

Length of the curve is found by formula:

$L(c) =  \;\;{\int_{\alpha}^{\beta} \! \sqrt{x'^2 + y'^2} \, dt }\;\;$

And I get this inside the integral:

$\int_{0}^{\pi/6}   \sqrt{324sin^2(6t) + (324 + 648cos(6t) + 324cos^2(6t)}  dt $

Then simplifying the integral:

$18 \cdot \int_{0}^{\pi/6}  \sqrt{1+1+2 \cos(6t)} dt$

$ 18 \sqrt{2} \int_{0}^{\pi/6} \sqrt{1+\cos(6t) \cdot \frac{1-\cos(6t)}{1-\cos(6t)}} = \sqrt{\frac{\sin^2(6t)}{1- \cos(6t)} } dt$

Then doing u-substitution = $1-\cos(6t)$ I end up with:

$-3 \sqrt{2} \int_{0}^{2} u^{-1/2} du$

Evaluates to:

$-6 \sqrt{2} \cdot (1-\cos(6 \cdot \frac{\pi}{6})^{1/2} - 0$

But it's wrong, why?

I also just tried by leaving u, and get -12, but it's not correct.

Comment: @SinisterCutlass  where do you get 36cos(6t)?

Comment: @IanMiller It seems like this formula is used: http://www.sapnaedu.in/wp-content/uploads/Square_numbers_1.png But why?You have a^2+b^2=1... doesn't make sense

Comment: You should have gotten positive 12 so you've just made a $\pm$ mistake somewhere. You working gets a bit sloppy - leaving out dt and du near the end so I'd look there.

Comment: WolframAlpha solution: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BSqrt%5BD%5B3Cos%5B6t%5D%2Ct%5D%5E2%2BD%5B18t%2B3Sin%5B6t%5D%2Ct%5D%5E2%5D%2C%7Bt%2C0%2CPi%2F6%7D%5D

Comment: @IanMiller 12 is correct.

Comment: 12 is the correct answer, however I don't understand why this: http://www.sapnaedu.in/wp-content/uploads/Square_numbers_1.png formula is used, you don't have (a+b)^2 here, but rather a^2+b^2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have erroneously introduced a minus sign when you have done your u-substitution. You were doing:

$$18\sqrt{2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{6}}\frac{\sin 6t}{\sqrt{1-\cos 6t}}dt$$

Let $u=1-\cos 6t$ so $du=6\sin 6t$

So your integral becomes:

$$3\sqrt{2}\int_0^2u^{-\frac{1}{2}}du$$